# When CLLocationManagerDelegate methods are called?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios8.1

I am using iOS8 and trying to track location(latitude and longitude) values. I needed clarification about when CLLocationManagerDelegate methods are called.

1)Will it be called only when app is in foreground along with locationchange OR

2)Will it be called when app is in background along with locationchange OR

3)In both the above conditions.

I just wanted to know/clarification about whether **- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations** is called even when app is in background along with locationchange OR only when app is in foreground along with locationchange OR in both conditions?

I have not enabled **Location Updates** Background Modes.I am using iOS8 and made necessary changes for location updates following the [link](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/).Using NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in my Info.plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you asked the user for location permission (you have `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseDescription` keys in your `info.plist`) then `didUpdateLocations` is:

- Always called when the app is in foreground mode
- NOT called when the application is in background unless you enabled the background location mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Then what is the difference between NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and enabling Background Location Mode.Can u clarify this please?

Comment: Two complete different things: `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` is the key in `info.plist`, the value is a question text which the user gets displayed when the app asks the user for permission to use the location services. Enabling background mode is an app property which must be set. It tells the iOS system that this app is allowed to update location data even when the app is in background mode.